# Somar dados de duas tabelas, com mesmos parâmetros

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho duas tabelas, a titulospagar e a titulosavulsos e em ambas eu tenho o campo placaMotorista e gostaria de somar os valores de cada uma

Gostaria de fazer uma query, juntando os dados delas em determinado tempo, dando GROUP BY em placaMotorista.

Fiz as duas queries a seguir, mas os valores retornam errados (muito grandes para cada placa).

```
SELECT SUM(a.valorTitulo) AS geralPlaca, SUM(b.valorTitulo) AS manutencaoPlaca, b.placaMotoristaTitulo AS placa
    FROM titulospagar a, titulosavulsos b
    WHERE a.dataVencimentoTitulo BETWEEN '$dataDe' AND '$dataAte' && b.dataTitulo BETWEEN '$dataDe' AND '$dataAte' && a.placaMotoristaTitulo = b.placaMotoristaTitulo && b.placaMotoristaTitulo != 'Nenhum'
    GROUP BY a.placaMotoristaTitulo, b.placaMotoristaTitulo
    ORDER BY a.placaMotoristaTitulo ASC, b.placaMotoristaTitulo ASC





SELECT SUM(titulospagar.valorTitulo) AS geralPlaca, SUM(titulosavulsos.valorTitulo) AS manutencaoPlaca, titulospagar.placaMotoristaTitulo AS placa
    FROM titulospagar INNER JOIN titulosavulsos ON titulospagar.placaMotoristaTitulo != 'Nenhum' && titulospagar.placaMotoristaTitulo = titulosavulsos.placaMotoristaTitulo &&  titulospagar.dataVencimentoTitulo BETWEEN '$dataDe' AND '$dataAte' && titulosavulsos.dataTitulo BETWEEN '$dataDe' AND '$dataAte'
    GROUP BY titulospagar.placaMotoristaTitulo, titulosavulsos.placaMotoristaTitulo
    ORDER BY titulospagar.placaMotoristaTitulo ASC
```

Em ambas retorna o mesmo valor para cada placa, mas o valor que retorna é errado.

Link do SQLFiddle, demonstrando o problema: [LINK](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4cdd5c/1)

Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço desde já!!

Comment: Acho que você deve especificar cada campo com colunas iguais antes por exemplo a.valorTitulo AS valor1....

Comment: eu especifiquei direto com o SUM, não posso especificar direto o campo, pois quero a somar de todo o período

Answer (score 0):

Tendo em conta apenas as placas existentes em ambas as tabelas, `titulospagar` e `titulosavulsos`:

```
SELECT      A.placa
        ,   A.valorTitulosPagar
        ,   B.valorTitulosAvulsos
FROM        (
                SELECT      placa
                        ,   SUM(valor) AS valorTitulosPagar
                FROM        titulospagar
                WHERE       data BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31' 
                GROUP BY    placa
            ) A
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT      placa
                        ,   SUM(valor) AS valorTitulosAvulsos
                FROM        titulosavulsos
                WHERE       data BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31' 
                GROUP BY    placa
            ) B ON B.placa = A.placa
ORDER BY    A.placa
```

Tendo em conta todas as placas existentes na tabela `placas` (se calhar a opção mais correta, porque existe a placa `EEE-4444` que apenas existe na tabela `titulosavulsos` e não é tida em conta na *query* acima):

```
SELECT      A.placas
        ,   A.valorTitulosPagar
        ,   B.valorTitulosAvulsos
FROM        (
                SELECT      p.placa
                        ,   SUM(IFNULL(TP.valor, 0)) AS valorTitulosPagar
                FROM        placas          P
                LEFT JOIN   titulospagar    TP  ON  TP.placa = P.placa 
                                                AND TP.data BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31' 
                GROUP BY    P.placa
            ) A
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT      p.placa
                        ,   SUM(IFNULL(ta.valor, 0)) AS valorTitulosAvulsos
                FROM        placas          P
                LEFT JOIN   titulosavulsos  TA  ON  TA.placa = P.placa 
                                                AND TA.data BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31' 
                GROUP BY    P.placa
            ) B ON B.placa = A.placa
ORDER BY    A.placa
```